# Question about the application of calculus in physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, calculus

The way I've been taught to apply calculus to physics problems is to consider a small element at a general position and write an equation for that element and then to integrate it.

For e.g 
[image]

To find the moment of inertia of this rod as a function of y, I write the equation for the moment of inertia of this element at a distance of y

$dI = dm y^2$ here $dm = \rho dy$ where $\rho$ is the density
Then I integrate this from $y = 0$ to $y = y$ to sum up the moment of inertia of these little elements up til the distance = $y$ to get the moment of inertia as a function of y

But I've never really understood this "procedure." Isn't $dI$ the infinitesimal $change$ in the moment of inertia function $I(y)$ for a change of $dy$ rather than the moment of inertia of this tiny element? Isn't what we should be trying to do is find the rate of change of $I(y)$ and integrate it w.r.t $y$ to the original function?

How can we just treat it as the moment of inertia of the tiny element and then sum these up using integration?

Comment: You can think of dI(y) as the infinitesimal change in the moment of inertia as the distance y increases from y to y+dy. You can also think of dI(y) as being the moment of inertia of the tiny element of the beam between y and y+dy. The two interpretations are effectively equivalent.

Comment: Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326637/understanding-the-differential-in-integrals/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question. You are misinterpreting the definition of the moment of inertia function $I(y)$. For a specific value of $y$, $I(y)$ does *not* mean "the contribution to the moment of inertia from the mass at distance $y$."  It means "the *total* moment of inertia due to *all* the masses between distance $0$ and distance $y$."  This is why, to find the moment of inertia of a rod of length $L$, you just plug in $y=L$ to get $I(L)$ instead of integrating the function. Since $I(y)$ is the total moment of inertia due to all the masses up to distance $y$, and $I(y + dy)$ is the total moment of inertia for a *slightly longer* rod, if you subtract the two, you get that $dI = I(y + dy) - I(y)$ is *just* the contribution to the moment of inertia from the length of rod at distance $y$.

In general, for these types of problems you have two functions you care about: a function $F(x)$ that represents "the sum of all the contributions from $0$ to $x$," and a function $f(x)$ that represents "the contribution *just* from the stuff at point $x$," which is typically some kind of density.  The key mathematical relation is that $f(x) = \frac{dF}{dx}$, or equivalently $F(x) = \int_0^x f(y)\ dy$.  In this case, $I(y)$ corresponds to the "integrated" function $F(x)$, not the "density" function $f(x)$.

Comment: What is the exact definition of moment of inertia?Suppose we are given a very big mass $M$ at a distance $r$,then the moment of inertia is $Mr^2$.Now while calculating the moment if inertia of the rod,why not we break into suppose 6 number of strips rather than infinitely many?What difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't enough letters in the alphabet to give every letter just one meaning in mathematics.

$d$ has a standard meaning in calculus. It is also sometimes used for the diameter of an object, or (as you said) to represent a small (but finite sized) change in some other quantity.

If you want to talk about "small changes" and "calculus" in the same equation, it would be better to use a different notation for a small change in $x$ like $\delta x$ or $\Delta x$, and only use $dx$ with its standard calculus meaning.

In your example, really you are saying that the inertia of a small part of the structure with mass $\Delta m$ is (approximately) $\Delta I = y^2 \Delta m$.

Summing over all the small parts, the inertia of the whole structure is then $$I = \sum_{\text{volume}} \Delta I = \sum_{\text{mass}} y^2 \Delta M = \sum_{\text{length}} y^2 \rho\, \Delta y.$$
In the limit as the individual $\Delta M$'s become smaller and smaller, you can replace the sum with an integral and (if the rod has length $L$) write
$$I = \int_0^L y^2 \rho\, dy.$$

Note: this didn't refer to anything like "the moment of inertia function $I(y)$". The M.I. of one specific rod isn't a "function" of anything - it's a constant! If you really wanted to write a function for the M.I. of *any* rod, it would be something like $I(\rho, L)$ not $I(y)$, because the M.I. depends on the density and the length of the rod. It does *not* depend on the arbitrary coordinate system (i.e. $y$) that you chose to do the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

> But I've never really understood this "procedure." Isn't dI the infinitesimal change in the moment of inertia function *I(y)* for a change of *dy* rather than the moment of inertia of this tiny element?

Italics mine.

The moment of inertia of a body about a given (as in your example) principal axis, is a single number [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Definition). It is for [rotational](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi.html) motions  what the mass is for linear motions, and it does not change depending on the y, only the choice of the rotational axis can change **I**

To get the mass of the sugar in a box of 100 pieces you only need to know the weight of one piece, which is your d**I**.